# Soundcloud Scrapy Spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to build a Scrapy Spider to parse the artist and track info from SoundCloud.

Using the developer tools in FireFox I've determined an API call can be made that returns a JSON object that converts to a python dictionary. This API call needs an artist ID, and as far as I can tell these IDs have been auto-incremented. This means I don't need to crawl the site, and can just have a list of starting URLs that make the initial API call and then parse the pages that follow from that. I believe this should make me more friendly to the site?

From the returned response the artists' URL can be obtained, and visiting and parsing this URL will give more information about the artist

From the artists' URL we can visit their tracks and scrape a list of tracks alongside the tracks' attributes.

I think the issues I'm having stem from not understanding Scrapy's framework...
If I directly put in the artists' URL is start_urls Scrapy passes a scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse Object to parse_artist. This allows me to extract the data I need (I didn't include all the code to parse the page to keep the code snippet shorter). However, if I pass that same Object to the same function from the function parse_api_call it results in an error...

I cannot understand why this is, and any help would be appreciated.

Side Note:
The initial API call grabs tracks from the artist, and the offset and limit can be changed and the function called recursively to collect the tracks. This, however, has proven unreliable, and even when it doesn't result in an error that terminates the program, it doesn't get a full list of tracks from the artist.

Here's the current code:

```
"""
Scrapes SoundCloud websites for artists and tracks
"""

import json
import scrapy
from ..items import TrackItem, ArtistItem
from scrapy.spiders.crawl import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor


class SoundCloudBot(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'soundcloudBot'
    allowed_domains = ['soundcloud.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/7436630/tracks?offset=0&limit=20&client_id=Q11Oe0rIPEuxvMeMbdXV7qaowYzlaESv&app_version=1556892058&app_locale=en',
        'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/4803918/tracks?offset=0&limit=20&client_id=Q11Oe0rIPEuxvMeMbdXV7qaowYzlaESv&app_version=1556892058&app_locale=en',
        'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/17364233/tracks?offset=0&limit=20&client_id=Q11Oe0rIPEuxvMeMbdXV7qaowYzlaESv&app_version=1556892058&app_locale=en',
        'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/19697240/tracks?offset=0&limit=20&client_id=Q11Oe0rIPEuxvMeMbdXV7qaowYzlaESv&app_version=1556892058&app_locale=en',
        'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/5949564/tracks?offset=0&limit=20&client_id=Q11Oe0rIPEuxvMeMbdXV7qaowYzlaESv&app_version=1556892058&app_locale=en'
    ]

    # This is added for testing purposes. When these links are added directly to the 
    # start_urls the code runs as expected, when these links are extracted using parse_api_call
    # is when problems arise

    # start_urls.extend([
    #     'https://soundcloud.com/futureisnow',
    #     'https://soundcloud.com/bigsean-1',
    #     'https://soundcloud.com/defjam',
    #     'https://soundcloud.com/ymcmbofficial',
    #     'https://soundcloud.com/walefolarin',
    #     # 'https://soundcloud.com/futureisnow/tracks',
    #     # 'https://soundcloud.com/bigsean-1/tracks',
    #     # 'https://soundcloud.com/defjam/tracks',
    #     # 'https://soundcloud.com/ymcmbofficial/tracks',
    #     # 'https://soundcloud.com/walefolarin/tracks'
    # ])

    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.url

        if url[:35] == 'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users':
            self.parse_api_call(response)
        # 'https://soundcloud.com/{artist}' 
        elif url.replace('https://soundcloud.com', '').count('/') == 1: # One starting forward slash for artist folder
            self.parse_artist(response)
        # 'https://soundcloud.com/{artist}/{track}' 
        elif url.replace('https://soundcloud.com', '').count('/') == 2 and url[-6:] == 'tracks':
            self.parse_tracks(response)

    def parse_api_call(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        artistItem = ArtistItem()

        first_track = data['collection'][0]
        artist_info = first_track.get('user')

        artist_id   = artist_info.get('id')
        artist_url  = artist_info.get('permalink_url')
        artist_name = artist_info.get('username')

        artistItem['artist_id'] = artist_id  
        artistItem['username']  = artist_name
        artistItem['url']       = artist_url

        artist_response = scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse(artist_url)
        self.parse_artist(artist_response)

        # Once the pipelines are written this will be changed to yeild 
        return artistItem


    def parse_artist(self, response):
        # This prints out <class 'scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse'>
        # It doesn't matter if start_urls get extend with artists' URLS or not
        print(type(response))

        data = response.css('script::text').extract()

        # This prints out a full HTML response if the function is called directly 
        # With scrapy, or an empty list if called from parse_api_call
        print(data)

        track_response = scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse(f'{response.url}/tracks')
        self.parse_tracks(track_response)


    def parse_tracks(self, response):
        pass
```

Comment: what error ? We can't read in your mind. Always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `start_urls` doesn't use `Response()` but `Request()` to send request to server and later it gives you `Response()` with data from server. But you have to also `yield Request()` or `return Requests()` from `parse_api_call` to main part of framework and then it will try to get data from server and it will run `parse()` to parse it - or you have to set other method in `Requests( ..., parse_artist )`

Comment: official documentation: [Request and Response](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
Request(url)
```

to get data from new url. But you can't execute it as normal function and get result at once. You have to use `return Request()` or `yield Request()` and scrapy puts it in queue to get data later.

After it gets data it uses method `parse()` to parse data from response. But you can set own method in request

```
Request(url, self.parse_artist)
```

But in `parse_artist()` you will not have access to data which you get in previous function so you have to send it in request using `meta` - ie.

```
Request(artistItem['url'], self.parse_artist, meta={'item': artistItem})
```

Full working code. You can put all in one file and run it without creating project.

It also saves result in `output.csv`

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
import json

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    allowed_domains = ['soundcloud.com']

    start_urls = [
        'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/7436630/tracks?offset=0&limit=20&client_id=Q11Oe0rIPEuxvMeMbdXV7qaowYzlaESv&app_version=1556892058&app_locale=en',
        'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/4803918/tracks?offset=0&limit=20&client_id=Q11Oe0rIPEuxvMeMbdXV7qaowYzlaESv&app_version=1556892058&app_locale=en',
        'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/17364233/tracks?offset=0&limit=20&client_id=Q11Oe0rIPEuxvMeMbdXV7qaowYzlaESv&app_version=1556892058&app_locale=en',
        'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/19697240/tracks?offset=0&limit=20&client_id=Q11Oe0rIPEuxvMeMbdXV7qaowYzlaESv&app_version=1556892058&app_locale=en',
        'https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/5949564/tracks?offset=0&limit=20&client_id=Q11Oe0rIPEuxvMeMbdXV7qaowYzlaESv&app_version=1556892058&app_locale=en'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        data = json.loads(response.text)

        if len(data['collection']) > 0:
            artist_info = data['collection'][0]['user']

            artistItem = {
                'artist_id': artist_info.get('id'),
                'username': artist_info.get('username'),
                'url':  artist_info.get('permalink_url'),
            }

            print('>>>', artistItem['url'])
            # make requests to url artistItem['url'],
            # parse response in parse_artist,
            # send artistItem to parse_artist
            return Request(artistItem['url'], self.parse_artist, meta={'item': artistItem})
        else:
            print("ERROR: no collections in data")


    def parse_artist(self, response):

        artistItem = response.meta['item']

        data = response.css('script::text').extract()

        # add data to artistItem
        #print(data)
        artistItem['new data'] =  'some new data'

        #print('>>>', response.urljoin('tracks'))
        print('>>>', response.url + '/tracks')
        # make requests to url artistItem['url'],
        # parse response in parse_tracks,
        # send artistItem to parse_tracks
        return Request(response.url + '/tracks', self.parse_tracks, meta={'item': artistItem})


    def parse_tracks(self, response):
        artistItem = response.meta['item']

        artistItem['tracks'] =  'some tracks'

        # send to CSV file
        return artistItem


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# run it without creating project
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0',
    # save in file as CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

`ouput.csv`

```
artist_id,username,url,new data,tracks
17364233,Def Jam Recordings,https://soundcloud.com/defjam,some new data,some tracks
4803918,Big Sean,https://soundcloud.com/bigsean-1,some new data,some tracks
19697240,YMCMB-Official,https://soundcloud.com/ymcmbofficial,some new data,some tracks
5949564,WALE,https://soundcloud.com/walefolarin,some new data,some tracks
```